# VBA Replace Using Regex

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I am trying to edit a XML file using a VBA code.The following is a sample of what i am trying to do

```
justification="left" dimensionsHeight="1" dimensionsWidth="19" characterOffset="0".
```

what I want is when I search through the document and if i find a string called justification i want to get rid of the text starts from the justification to the length of the characters that i specify. For Eg: I want to get rid from justification upto `dimensionswidth="19"`  in this case and my result should contain just `characterOffset="0"`. I am trying to use Instr & Replace functions but the problem is that the characters in quotes are variables and my code is not working for all cases.
Any ideas guys

This is the code i have now

```
If InStr(1, LinesB(j), "Justification") Then

LinesB(j) = Replace(LinesB(j), "justification=" + Chr(34) + "left" + Chr(34) + "dimensionsHeight=" + Chr(34) + "1" + Chr(34) + "dimensionsWidth=" + Chr(34) + "19", "")

End If
```

Comment: "the problem is that the characters in quotes are variables and my code is not working for all cases"  show us what you have so far

Comment: "to get rid of the text starts from the justification to the length of the characters that i specify". How are you going to ge the length here?

Comment: @Matt.G I am asking  whether there is any way i can specify a length of characters i can omit.

Comment: what is your criteria for identifying the length? is it ending with dimensionswidth=".." or anything before characterOffset?

Comment: @Matt.G anything before characteroffset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regex: `justification.*?(?=\scharacterOffset)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fQeZPq/1)

See this [link](https://analystcave.com/excel-regex-tutorial/#Regex_Replace_pattern_in_a_string) on how to replace using regex in VBA

Sample:

```
Dim regex As Object, str As String
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")

With regex
  .Pattern = "justification.*?(?=\scharacterOffset)"
End With

str = "justification="left" dimensionsHeight="1" dimensionsWidth="19" characterOffset="0""   'might need to escape "
Debug.Print regex.Replace(str, "") 
'Result: characterOffset="0"
```

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate the usage of this in a vba code an example or something. I am just a beginner.

Comment: @george86, I have edited the answer to include VBA sample code. Please note that I've not tested it

Comment: My vba script is working good & i want share that excel file with my co-workers so that they can also use it without seeing the code that i made.What will be the best way of doing that. Can i make it like a web app or something?